# Weight Normalization causing nan in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, nan

I am using weight normalization inbuilt in PyTorch 1.2.0. When the weights of a layer using weight norm becomes close to 0, the weight norm operation results in `NaN` which then propagates through the entire network. To fix this, I want to add a small value like `eps = 1e-6` to the norm of `weight_v` in the PyTorch weight norm function.

So I attempted to locate the function on my local computer and found it at  `miniconda3/envs/pytorch1_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/utils/weight_norm.py` ([GitHub code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cb90e36684b638fd4cb33b1cdf23c22a96fd9806/torch/nn/utils/weight_norm.py#L8)) and tried to modify it.

I wanted to find which function was computing the weight norm so I added `hi` inside each function and found that the `compute_weight` [function](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cb90e36684b638fd4cb33b1cdf23c22a96fd9806/torch/nn/utils/weight_norm.py#L15) is called before every forward pass.

This function was calling `_weight_norm` function stored at `miniconda3/envs/pytorch1_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset9.py` ([GitHub code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/cb90e36684b638fd4cb33b1cdf23c22a96fd9806/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset9.py#L958)). When I add `print("hi")` inside that `_weight_norm` function but it didn't get printed.

So what is the correct way to modify the weight norm code by adding the `eps` to norm of the weight? Perhaps can replace the `_weight_norm` function on my local computer with that of the latest PyTorch 1.9.0 [version](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/6db8f7a70920f91418078fe09477eed0b0adefdb/torch/onnx/symbolic_opset9.py#L2971) but not sure how to add `eps`.

Comment: I believe the `_weight_norm` is actually in the `torch._C._VariableFunctions` instead of the `onnx/symbolic_opset9.py`.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen Ok will check and revert back. Can we edit C++/C codes?

Comment: You'll probably need to compile it after edit. But I have no idea where that file is.

Comment: You better should post an GitHub issue for PyTorch discussing this, as this might be relevant for others as well. Or discuss this in the official PyTorch discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Found a temporary solution at https://github.com/facebookresearch/multiface/blob/main/models.py#L580

so instead of using the regular `nn.conv2d` use

```
class Conv2dWN(nn.Conv2d):
    def __init__(
        self,
        in_channels,
        out_channels,
        kernel_size,
        stride=1,
        padding=0,
        dilation=1,
        groups=1,
        bias=True,
    ):
        super(Conv2dWN, self).__init__(
            in_channels,
            out_channels,
            kernel_size,
            stride,
            padding,
            dilation,
            groups,
            True,
        )
        self.g = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(out_channels))

    def forward(self, x):
        wnorm = torch.sqrt(torch.sum(self.weight**2))
        return F.conv2d(
            x,
            self.weight * self.g[:, None, None, None] / wnorm,
            bias=self.bias,
            stride=self.stride,
            padding=self.padding,
            dilation=self.dilation,
            groups=self.groups,
        )
```